# pandoc document conversion error in rmarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc, r-markdown, knitrbootstrap

I just updated RStudio from 0.98.1028 to 0.98.1074 (latest as of today) and started hitting the error below ([RStudio support forum](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202297207-Knit-HTML-Error-pandoc-document-conversion-failed-with-error-97)) on a knit-to-HTML script which worked previously. It seems like this may be due to caching, but I have `opts_chunk$set(cache=F)` at the beginning of my .Rmd.

```
pandoc: Could not find data file templates/default.html
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 97
Execution halted
```

Other possibly relevant items:

- I'm using knitrBootstrap v1.0.0
- I'm on Ubuntu
- The analysis outputs graphics in ggplot and kable form, but the error remained when commenting those out